# Joining two tables in Access

Tags: ms-access, join

I have a situation which I would like some help with. Basically, I have three tables - lets say they are CARS, SHOWROOM1, SHOWROOM2 and lets say the situation is SHOWROOM1 and SHOWROOM2 are car show rooms that might or might not have cars in the CARS table.

What I would like is join between the SHOWROOM1 and SHOWROOM2 tables grouped by CARID in the CARS table. The way this join should work is that if a car matches atleast one row in either showroom, then that row should be returned. So if a car exists in both showrooms thats fine and both can be returned, but if it only exists in one showroom then that record should be pulled up, with a "null" value for the other showroom's row. I am after something like a full outer join but I know Access does not support it... Please could someone help me achieve this?

Comment: Two tables named SHOWROOM1 and SHOWROOM2 smells like a bad database design.  What you are describing is a many-to-many relationship.  I would suggest the following approach: table CARS with CarID column, table SHOWROOMS with ShowroomID column, table SHOWROOM_CARS with columns ShowroomID and CarID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate a FULL OUTER JOIN using a LEFT JOIN UNIONED together with a RIGHT JOIN:

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.x = T2.x
UNION
SELECT x, y, z FROM T1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.x = T2.x
```